# update tabla SQLITE por user input en python

Tags: python, sqlite

Buenas noches estoy tratando de poder actualizar un valor de la tabla que tengo previamente creada,

este es el query de la base de datos

```
query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PELICULAS
( ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  NOMBRE  TEXT NOT NULL,
  DIRECTOR TEXT NOT NULL,
  CATEGORIA   TEXT NOT NULL,
  DURACION   TIME NOT NULL,
  GENERO TEXT NOT NULL,
  ID_CUIDADES TEXT NOT NULL,
  ID_ESTADOS TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUIDADES) REFERENCES CUIDADES(ID)
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADOS) REFERENCES ESTADOS(ID)
);""")
```

connection.execute(query)

y este el codigo que estoy tratando de hacer, no me marca ningun error solamente me sale una leyenda que puse si algo pasaba mal "Error updating person information"

les comparto el codigo

```
import sqlite3
import os

database = 'cinema.db'
connect = None

# Check if database file exists.
if not os.path.isfile(database):

    # Confirm incorrect database location and stop program execution.
    print("Error locating database.")
    quit()

try:

    # Connect to database.
    connect = sqlite3.connect(database)

except sqlite3.DatabaseError as e:

    # Confirm unsuccessful connection and quit.
    print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
    quit()

# Cursor to execute query.
cursor = connect.cursor()

# Query parameters.
NOMBRE  = input("INGRESE ID")


# SQL to update data in the person table.
sqlUpdate = \
    "UPDATE PELICULAS \
     SET NOMBRE= ?, \
     WHERE NOMBRE= ?"

try:

    # Execute query and commit changes.
    cursor.execute(sqlUpdate, (NOMBRE))
    connect.commit()

    # Confirm successful updating of person information.
    print("Person information updated successfully.")

except sqlite3.DatabaseError as e:

    # Confirm error updating person information and stop program execution.
    print("Error updating person information.")
    quit()

finally:

    # Close database connection.
    connect.close()
```

Despues de ejecutar el codigo no muestra errores solamente no se actualiza la base de datos no estoy seguro que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Imprime también la variable `e` para que veas que error aparece, no solamente tu mensaje porque se pierde el error

Comment: No se me habia ocurrido tenia error de syntaxis en WHERE gracias.

Comment: Como era un error pequeño que se resolvió en los comentarios es probable que esta pregunta termine cerrada, también puedes eliminarla si lo prefieres. Saludos!